# AG Grid ToolTips in Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am having a problem implementing AG Grids ToolTip. When i follow the Example at https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/angular/component-tooltip/#example-custom-tooltip-component and try to

```
import { ITooltipAngularComp } from '@ag-grid-community/angular';
```

I get this error

> Cannot find module '@ag-grid-community/angular' or its corresponding
> type declarations.

I import it like this normally

```
`import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid-community'`;
```

but when i Import it like this

```
`import { ITooltipAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-community'`
```

I get this below error so i am a bit lost. I am by the way on version 25.x

> Module '"../../../../../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/main"' has
> no exported member 'ITooltipAngularComp'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming your imports are like this:

```
"ag-grid-community": "^25.0.1",
"ag-grid-angular": "^25.0.1",
```

I think the ITooltipAngularComp import should look like this:

```
import { ITooltipAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
```

Comment: Here is what i have in my package.json
   "ag-grid-angular": "^25.0.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.0.1",

Comment: Can you try the package names I've suggested? They are for Ag Grid Modules, so you might also need to add a call to `ModuleRegistry.registerModules([])'.  Also what version of Angular you on?

Comment: It seems even there own docs are not consistent as some refer to the import the way i do it but then some look for items the way you specify it. I will have to play arround and see if it works as my app has 100+ components that use the grid and i cant just break it for tool tip

Comment: I just updated my answer after i noticed you were trying to import the angular tooltip component from the ag-grid-community package instead of the ag-grid-angular one!